# Given m bit strings of length n, find if there exist a set of exactly k bit strings such that at each position, only 1 bit string has a set bit

Tags: algorithm

That was a mouthful, so let me explain.

Let's say we have a set of `4` bit strings of length `3` -- `{001, 100, 111, 010}` and `k = 3`

The answer here is `true` because of the set `{001, 100, 010}` as at each position `{0 .. n - 1}` in the bit strings, there is only one bit string that has a set bit. Note that in the required sub-set, there should be **exactly one set bit at each position.**

Another example, consider `{10001, 01000, 00110}` and `k = 3`. The answer here is `true` again.

The same would not be true if `k = 2` because we want the required set to have a cardinality of `k.`

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: (I take the question to be `How to decide the existence of a cover with the constraints described in sub-exponential time?` (and the answer to be "No-one knows, and many would be dumbfounded to learn.")) Trivial if `m = k` (second example). Strings with no bit set help reach `k` if there is a smaller cover; let the other strings be unique. The number of bits set has to add up to `n`. As strings with more bits set exclude more others, start there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is NP hard because if you could solve this problem then you could solve the [Exact set cover problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover) in polynomial time.  However, exact set cover is known to be NP-complete.

Comment: Are there any heuristics that I could use to solve this problems for small input sizes?

Comment: For very small problems you can just use brute force - otherwise Google for Donald Knuth's Dancing Links algorithm.

Comment: However my problem is a bit simpler, I don't want to find the exact sub-set, I just want to find out if one exists.

Comment: @adijo Unfortunately that is no easier.  Suppose you had a way of determining the existence of a set, then you could simply remove one of the bit strings and use your method to see if a cover still exists.  If not, then you discover that the bit string you removed _must_ be in the set cover.  In other words, determining the existence of a cover is basically the same problem as finding an instance of a cover.

Comment: ...isn't this *exactly* the Exact Cover Problem?

Comment: @user4235730 Pretty much, except exact cover doesn't bother with the restriction to having a cover with exactly k elements.